# Split a git repository to work on two projects at the same time

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I am developing a **framework** to use on my projects; however, the developing of a framework can go so far without context: i.e. I need to start using it in real-life projects and see specifically what **I need to add, fix, or adjust** (maybe things that worked on a testing environment don't work for real-life situation, or some things don't make sense, or I want to add features).

First of all, since **Framework** is obviously a work in progress, I need to be sure that it is kept updated within **Real-life project** as a different part of it, so I can go back to Framework, edit it, commit, go back to Real-life project update Framework within, go on working with the project.

Second, I would actually like a way to achieve this without doing the project switching. What I mean is that I would like to be able to edit **Framework** within **Real-life project** and push those commits to the **Framework** repository.

Now, I know that the tools to achieve this are most likely `git submodule` and `git subtree`, but both of them are pretty confusing. Submodule, especially, seems it is more oriented towards a *read-only* approach (e.g. keep your libraries always updated): this would satisfy my first requirement, but not the second.

Any pointers on how to achieve this with Git and how the workflow would look like?

Comment: There might be a better way, but when forced to use one repo, I've done side project work in a branch which was periodically merged back into my main project branch. This is not painless and not ideal, but it can work. As workflows go, it's easier if you're using a graphical git client.

Comment: in similar situations i just used two formally independent repos and put one into an ignored subfolder of the other

Comment: For the second requirement, you can check git-work-dir script which is available in contrib directory of git source code.  


(through symlinking, this script creates a new working directory whose history is shared with the original repository:



git-new-workdir an/existing/repo new/directory





The new directory and the files within can be thought of as a clone, except since the history is shared, the two trees automatically stay in sync. There’s no need to merge, push, or pull)

Answer (score 4):

Any of the two approaches would serve you.

Each one can allow what you need, to edit the project in place and to push that specific content to a separate repositories.

Both approaches would also incur in an amount of overhead in order to keep both projects running.

About the two points you mention:

- With Submodules you would have a repository inside a folder of other repository. The outer one (Real-Life) keeps saved in a file the location of your submodule (Framework) repository, and the current commit being used. When you want to edit Framework you just go to the sub-folder where it is stored, and inside there it should behave as if you where in a completely separate git repository with its own remote and history. After modifying Framework you return back to Real-Life and update the submodule references. The process would look usually like this:

  ```
  Edit files in Framework
  Move to Framework subfolder
  Stage, commit, and push changes to Framework repository
  Go back to Real-Life folder
  Update Real-Life submodule reference
  ```
- With Subtrees you work with Real-Life and Framework in the same repository, still keeping Framework code under a specific sub-folder. When you change content in Framework you still commit those Real-Life repository as if was a single project. What the subtree tools allow is that you can isolate the changes that you have in the Framework folder and create from these a set of commits that exists separate from Real-Life, this commits will contain Framework-only changes and can be pushed the the Framework repository. The process would look like this:

  ```
  Edit files in Framework
  Stage, commit, and push to Real-Life repository
  Create Framework commits using subtree tools
  Push Framework specific commits to Framework repository
  ```

**If you are still unsure of the trade backs that exist between these two I would suggest that you go with using submodules**. You will find more documentation, use cases, and is generally less complex. It has some short-comings but by being familiar with submodules first you could gauge what subtrees offer. More [info about submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: The way I had understood `submodule` is as a read-only solution; the docs state: *you cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main project.* On the other hand, it looks like `subtree` *merges* the histories of the two projects which I'd rather keep separate.

Comment: Subtree does indeed merges histories. Your `reallife` project would contain in its history commits of its own and `framework` since it contains it. The `framework` project however, being the independent one, can be kept clean and completely separate from any `reallife` content. About the "read-only" part in submodules, it could be a misunderstanding. You can completely modify the contents in a submodule since each submodule is a repository on its own.

Comment: Using `subtree` seems like it will make **Framework** lose its independence, somewhat. While I would like to go with `submodules` at this point (as you originally suggested), I am really wary: I don't know if it is a misunderstanding, but the quote is from [**the manual**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (under **Description**, 2nd paragraph); this makes me believe that, even if you can, perhaps you **shouldn't**. And there are a few [**articles**](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/) pointing out to the mess it can bring to.

Comment: Here's another: http://somethingsinistral.net/blog/git-submodules-are-probably-not-the-answer/

Comment: The "you cannot modify the contents" still means that `reallife` and `framework` are kept in separate repositories, thus `reallife` cannot create or push commits to `framework`, nor viceversa. Each one cannot modify the other. Still, having a submodule means that `reallife` will be a aware that a given revision of `framework` is living within a folder of `reallife`. Each repository can still be modified freely and independently.